# SSAS Tabular/Analysis services Many-to-Many for Multiple curriencies input - Multiple currencies output

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

I am trying to create on the fly currencies conversion from many currencies input ( InvoicesHeaders rows have differents currencies , so each row have an amount and the currency code for this amount) and many currencies output ( each affiliate want to see figures with it's own currency ).

Therefore I end up in a many to many, join between the InvoiceTable and the currency table. To join them I create in SQL a concatenated field with the day and the currency code.
[image]

[image: Link Invoice to Currency]

Then ( reusing tutorial from internet ) I create a calculation doing a lookup  from the Invoice to the rate.

```
Amount adj:=SUMX(Invoices,Invoices[TotalInvoiceAmount]/LOOKUPVALUE(ExchangeRatesPerDay[Rate],ExchangeRatesPerDay[ToCurrencyConcatenatedday112],Invoices[CurrencyCodeConcatenateInvoiceDate112]))
```

However, when I am trying to use this measure in excel (filtering on one currency at the time of course ) I am getting an error message saying many rows where pass but only one was expected.

[image]

From the error message, it looks like the lookup is getting multiple values which is strange because in the excel I am filtering on one currency. Therefore for each combination of day+currencycode there is only one row. I check the SQL using this query

```
with cte as (
SELECT  [RateTypeName]
      ,[FromCurrency]
      ,[ToCurrency]
      ,[StartDate]
      ,[Rate]
      ,[EndDate]
      ,[ConversionFactor]
      ,[RateTypeDescription]
      ,[dday]
      ,[dday112]
      ,[ToCurrencyConcatenatedday112]
      ,[FromCurrencyConcatenatedday112]
        , count(*) over (partition by [ToCurrencyConcatenatedday112],FromCurrency ) as co
  FROM [stg].[ExchangeRatesPerDay]
  )

  select * from cte where co>1
```

And it doesn't return any record.

I will appreciate any idea you may have.

Regards

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why my answer have been deleted. Anynay I am posting it back : I found this website https://www.kasperonbi.com/currency-conversion-in-dax-for-power-bi-and-ssas/ that provide an answer. I have been using this logic in production for over a month and it work great.